# Pyspark: how are dataframe describe() and summary() implemented

Tags: python, oop, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to know how `df.describe()` and `df.summary()` is implemented

As in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.summary

```
def summary(self, *statistics):
    if len(statistics) == 1 and isinstance(statistics[0], list):
        statistics = statistics[0]
    jdf = self._jdf.summary(self._jseq(statistics))
    return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
```

I'm not very familliar with OO in python and I'm a bit confused. Where is the quantile and other statistics implemented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `jdf` is a reference to Java `Dataset` object accessed through Py4j.
- Python code calls its `summary` method:

  ```py
  jdf = self._jdf.summary(self._jseq(statistics))
  ```
- [`Dataset.summary` calls `StatFunctions.summary` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2473)

  ```scala
  def summary(statistics: String*): DataFrame = StatFunctions.summary(this, statistics.toSeq)
  ```
- Which [is implemented](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a8a5cd24e2b9255acbc1e946f2946928144568ae/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/stat/StatFunctions.scala#L229-L297) like this:

  ```scala
  def summary(ds: Dataset[_], statistics: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {


    val defaultStatistics = Seq("count", "mean", "stddev", "min", "25%", "50%", "75%", "max")
    val selectedStatistics = if (statistics.nonEmpty) statistics else defaultStatistics


    val percentiles = selectedStatistics.filter(a => a.endsWith("%")).map { p =>
      try {
        p.stripSuffix("%").toDouble / 100.0
      } catch {
        case e: NumberFormatException =>
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unable to parse $p as a percentile", e)
      }
    }
    require(percentiles.forall(p => p >= 0 && p <= 1), "Percentiles must be in the range [0, 1]")


    var percentileIndex = 0
    val statisticFns = selectedStatistics.map { stats =>
      if (stats.endsWith("%")) {
        val index = percentileIndex
        percentileIndex += 1
        (child: Expression) =>
          GetArrayItem(
            new ApproximatePercentile(child, Literal.create(percentiles)).toAggregateExpression(),
            Literal(index))
      } else {
        stats.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) match {
          case "count" => (child: Expression) => Count(child).toAggregateExpression()
          case "mean" => (child: Expression) => Average(child).toAggregateExpression()
          case "stddev" => (child: Expression) => StddevSamp(child).toAggregateExpression()
          case "min" => (child: Expression) => Min(child).toAggregateExpression()
          case "max" => (child: Expression) => Max(child).toAggregateExpression()
          case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$stats is not a recognised statistic")
        }
      }
    }


    val selectedCols = ds.logicalPlan.output
      .filter(a => a.dataType.isInstanceOf[NumericType] || a.dataType.isInstanceOf[StringType])


    val aggExprs = statisticFns.flatMap { func =>
      selectedCols.map(c => Column(Cast(func(c), StringType)).as(c.name))
    }


    // If there is no selected columns, we don't need to run this aggregate, so make it a lazy val.
    lazy val aggResult = ds.select(aggExprs: _*).queryExecution.toRdd.collect().head


    // We will have one row for each selected statistic in the result.
    val result = Array.fill[InternalRow](selectedStatistics.length) {
      // each row has the statistic name, and statistic values of each selected column.
      new GenericInternalRow(selectedCols.length + 1)
    }


    var rowIndex = 0
    while (rowIndex < result.length) {
      val statsName = selectedStatistics(rowIndex)
      result(rowIndex).update(0, UTF8String.fromString(statsName))
      for (colIndex <- selectedCols.indices) {
        val statsValue = aggResult.getUTF8String(rowIndex * selectedCols.length + colIndex)
        result(rowIndex).update(colIndex + 1, statsValue)
      }
      rowIndex += 1
    }


    // All columns are string type
    val output = AttributeReference("summary", StringType)() +:
      selectedCols.map(c => AttributeReference(c.name, StringType)())


    Dataset.ofRows(ds.sparkSession, LocalRelation(output, result))
  }
  ```